# How to join two lines created by curvature pen tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, print-production, pen-tool, line-art

I am trying to use curvature pen tool to draw shapes, but unable to draw further lines on this shape with curvature tool. how to join curvature pen tool line with another pen tool line in illustrator???

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more? Maybe adding screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to join two lines/paths drawn by curvature tool.

1. If you've drawn a path, click on it using curvature tool. It will start again from the end you had ended it.
2. If you hover on either ends when path is selected, you'll see small circle with a dot which denotes that you can continue path from here.
3. When drawing a new path, you can move it towards the end of another path and click on the end, it will join both.
4. You can alternatively use <kbd>Cntl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join two ends. Just select both ends with Direct Selection too.

You can observe them in following GIF:
[image]

Sometimes, if you'll need Direct Selection tool to perform steps like this:

[image]

Feel free to use Pen tool itself where you need to.